# Vague SyntaxError only when publishing

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, publishing

Currently trying to publish a site created in ASP.NET. Locally it works fine, but the publish environment throws

[image]

in the Chrome console, the Firefox console, and the IE console. I've double and triple checked braces, and since it runs fine locally I don't think that's the issue.

Honestly, since the error is so vague I'm not sure what information to include here. I will watch this and add information about the project as requested.